# Unable to bind checkboxes even after registering custom property editor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I've the following sequence of steps to register a team:

1. Select Team - This will display the list of players of this team as check boxes (JSP page below)
2. User can select one or more players displayed
3. `newdTeam` request handler method should be called setting the selected players from step 2 above. The handler is being called but the `players` set is empty even if I've selected players in step 2. Not sure where the issue is.

I doesn't see the property editor invoked. Any help is appreciated.

**Team**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Team
{
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;

    @GraphProperty
    @Indexed (unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo (type = "PLAYED_WITH_TEAM", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private final Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = StringUtil.capitalizeFirstLetter(name);
    }

    public Long getNodeId()
    {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public Collection<Player> getPlayers()
    {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Set<Player> plyrs)
    {
        System.err.println("called set plrs");
        players.addAll(plyrs);
    }
}
```

**Player**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Player
{
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;

    @Indexed (unique = true)
    private String name;

    @GraphProperty
    @Indexed
    private String firstName;

    @GraphProperty
    private String email;

        //getters and setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/registration")
public class RegistrationController
{
    private transient final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private LeagueRepository leagueRepo;

    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepo;

    @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get()
    {
        return "/registration/start";
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping (value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String hasParticipatedEarlier(@RequestParam boolean participatedInEarlierLeague, Model model)
    {
        if (participatedInEarlierLeague)
        {
            LOG.debug("Participated in earlier leagues. Retrieving the past league teams.");
            Iterable<League> allLeagues = leagueRepo.findAll();
            Set<League> sortedLeagues = new TreeSet<League>();
            for (League l: allLeagues)
            {
                sortedLeagues.add(l);
            }
            LOG.debug("Past leagues sorted by start date {}", sortedLeagues);
            model.addAttribute("pastLeagues", sortedLeagues);
        }
        else
        {
            LOG.debug("Did not participate in earlier leagues. Redirecting to register the new one.");
        }
        return "/registration/leagues";
    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/selectTeam", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String selectTeam(@RequestParam Long selectedTeam, Model model)
    {
        LOG.debug("Participated as team {} in previous league", selectedTeam);
        Team team = teamRepo.findOne(selectedTeam);
        model.addAttribute("team", team);
        model.addAttribute("players", team.getPlayers());
        return "registration/players";
    }

    @RequestMapping (value = "/newTeam", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newdTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team, Model model)
    {
        LOG.debug("Selected players from existing list {}", team.getPlayers());

        return "registration/registrationConfirmation";
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Player.class, new PlayerPropertyEditor());
    }
}
```

**PlayerPropertyEditor**

```
public class PlayerPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
{
    @Autowired
    PlayerRepository playerRepo;

    @Override
    public String getAsText()
    {
        System.err.println("get as txt");
        return ((Player) getValue()).getNodeId().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String incomingId) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        System.err.println(incomingId);
        Player player = playerRepo.findOne(Long.valueOf(incomingId));
        setValue(player);
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Players of ${team.name}</title>

</head>
<body>
    <f:form action="newTeam" method="post" modelAttribute="team">
        <f:checkboxes items="${players}" path="players" itemLabel="name" itemValue="nodeId" delimiter="<br/>"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </f:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I see is that you inject `PlayerRepository` inside `PlayerPropertyEditor`, which has no effect, since it is not in a Spring context. You should pass it through a constructor. And then inject it in the `Controller`

**PlayerPropertyEditor**

```
public class PlayerPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
{
    private PlayerRepository playerRepo;

    public PlayerPropertyEditor(PlayerRepository playerRepo) {
        this.playerRepo = playerRepo;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

inside **Controller**

```
@Autowired
private PlayerRepository playerRepo;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Player.class, new PlayerPropertyEditor(playerRepo));
}
```

Secondly, and I guess that this is the main issue, is that you should override `equals` and `hashCode` for your `Player` class. I haven't tested that, but I rely on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718318/852300)