# Spring MVC form checkbox not checked when retriving data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am setting status property as `true` in the background but still check box not checked:

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${someFormList}" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form:checkbox path="status" items="${list.status}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller:

```
model.addObject("someFormList", someFormList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Path gets you partway there. Add the `value` property to the form:checkbox tag:

`<form:checkbox path="status" value="${status}" />`

Instead of `addObject`, you may want to try `addAttribute` (see also this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718318/2074605)).